# StackOverflowError occurs everytime i try to fix the code

Tags: java, junit, fractions, stack-overflow, greatest-common-divisor

I was writing a program that adds 2 fractions. I have 3 classes: UI, Rechnen and RechnenTest. The UI and RechnenTest classes were given and  I had to write the Rechnen class, that adds the fractions. The problem is, the program works good but the JUnit Test fails. These are the classes:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class UserInterface {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            String[] userData = getData_Dialog();
            if (userData == null)
                break;
            int z1 = 0;
            int n1 = 0;
            int z2 = 0;
            int n2 = 0;
            try {
                z1 = Integer.parseInt(userData[0]);
                n1 = Integer.parseInt(userData[1]);
                z2 = Integer.parseInt(userData[2]);
                n2 = Integer.parseInt(userData[3]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Bitte nur ganze Zahlen eingeben, Nenner != 0");
                continue;
            }
            try {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Summe: " + Rechnen.bruchAddition(z1, n1, z2, n2));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                JOptionPane
                        .showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Mindestens eine der Zahlen war nicht im vorgebenen Bereich");
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Danke und auf Wiedersehen!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static String[] getData_Dialog() {
        JTextField z1TF = new JTextField();
        JTextField n1TF = new JTextField();
        JTextField z2TF = new JTextField();
        JTextField n2TF = new JTextField();
        Object[] message = { "Zaehler 1", z1TF, "Nenner 1", n1TF, "Zaehler 2",
                z2TF, "Nenner 2", n2TF };
        Object[] options = { "Addition", "Abbruch" };
        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(new JFrame(), message,
                "Brueche Addieren", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
        if (n == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) { // Zustimmung
            return new String[] { z1TF.getText(), n1TF.getText(),
                    z2TF.getText(), n2TF.getText() };
        } else if (n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION // Verneinung
                || n == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) { // Dialogfenster
                                                        // geschlossen
            return null;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Rechnen {

    public static String bruchAddition(int z1, int n1, int z2, int n2)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        int m = (z1 * n2) + (z2 * n1);
        int n = (n1 * n2);

        if (n1 <= 0 || n2 <= 0 || z1 < 0 || z2 < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        }
        return m / ggt(m, n) + "/" + n / ggt(m, n);

    }


    public static int max(int x, int y) {

        return x > y ? x : y;
    }


    public static int min(int x, int y) {

        return x > y ? y : x;
    }

    public static int ggt(int x, int y) {

        return (x == y) ? x : ggt(max(x, y) - min(x, y), min(x, y));
    }
}
```

---

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class RechnenTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals("Zaehler = 1 Nenner = 1",
                rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(1, 3, 2, 3));
        assertEquals("Zaehler = 1 Nenner = 1",
                rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(5, 8, 3, 8));
        assertEquals("Zaehler = 1 Nenner = 1",
                rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(10, 16, 3, 8));
        assertEquals("Zaehler = 1 Nenner = 3",
                rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(-1, 3, 2, 3));
        assertEquals("Zaehler = -1 Nenner = 2",
                rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(0, 2, -1, 2));
        assertEquals("Zaehler = -2 Nenner = 3",
                rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(-1, 3, 1, -3));
        try {
            rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(1, 1, 1, 0);
            fail();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            assertTrue(true);
        }
        try {
            rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1, 1, 1);
            fail();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            assertTrue(true);
        }
        assertEquals("Zaehler = 1 Nenner = " + Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1,
                        Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }
}
```

The language is german.

Thanks

Comment: Each of your asserts should be in their own unit test!

Comment: Can you provide some translation for us non German speakers? What is the numerators and what is the denominators in this function signature? `public static String bruchAddition(int z1, int n1, int z2, int n2)`

Comment: as @dshiga said, I had to change the return String format in `bruchAddition` and then it worked. The `bruchAddition` accepts negative numerators because the test demands that, but then I get `java.lang.StackOverflowError`, I don't know how to fix it, so that I don't any errors when running the `JUnit Test`.

`z1, z2` are numerators
`n1, n2` are denominators.

Answer (score 1):

When I run the code myself, I get:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[Zaehler = 1 Nenner = ]1> but was:<[1/]1>
```

The test is expecting `bruchAddition` to return a String with a different format. You can fix the problem by changing the last line of `bruchAddition` to:

```
return "Zaehler = " + m / ggt(m, n) + " Nenner = " + n / ggt(m, n);
```

That gets us through the first three assertions, but then the call to `Rechnen.bruchAddition(-1, 3, 2, 3)` fails with an `IllegalArgumentException`. This is because `bruchAddition` rejects calls where z1 or z2 < 0.

If you change `bruchAddition` to accept negative z1 and z2 (as the unit test requires), then you get a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` due to `ggt` calling itself recursively and apparently not ending the recursion properly.

Your technique for finding the greatest common divisor with `ggt`, `max` and `min` seems to be broken. `min(1, -3)` returns -3. Are you sure that's what you want? I have a feeling your algorithm needs it to return 1 in this case, i.e. the smallest absolute value.

Comment: As you said, I changed the String format and it worked.
But how can I fix the `java.lang.StackOverflowError`?

Comment: It's hard to know why `ggt` is failing without knowing what it's trying to do. Could you edit the question to explain the purpose of `ggt`? The fact that it's failing only when one of the arguments is negative suggests that there's something wrong with the logic for that case. It might be a good idea to also edit the title of the question to clarify that the test is not to blame - something needs fixing in the class being tested.

Comment: `ggt` is the `Greatest common divisor`